# Azure Storage Table Query Coming Up Feature?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Do azure team plan on introducing new query feature like skip,contains etc in future, where can i find what are the new feature/functionality that will be available in future.
Thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic since it's inquiring about roadmap/future features of a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend following [Azure Storage blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/) for announcements. In addition, you can also share your ideas or features you would like to see at [Azure Feedback Storage forum](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage).

Comment: Yes i have already requested for the feature, thanks for the blog link.
From feature request forum one can know what feature are being requested reviewed  and picked by the azure team, but what are they currently planning any short or long term vision is not clear i was just wondering if they disclose such information or not, that would have been helpful.